# Design pattern suitable for messenger like ICQ, skype, pidgin..[WPF-C#]

Tags: design-patterns

I need advance I am newbie in design pattern. I am developing messenger like ICQ, Skype, Pidgin-this is school project, it does not work with ICQ, Skype protocol, it works with own protocol.

This messenger provides this functionality{methods}:

*Log on on sever
*Load contact list
*Send message
*Recieve message
*Send comment
*LogOff

These methods are grouped in one class called XCommands.

User data(ID, password, cookies, some settings) are grouped in class called XAvatar.

All methods of class XCommads accepts as argument object type of XAvatar + other arguments.

I think this is very bad design. I search with google one hour but I find any solution for my problem.

Could someone advise what design pattern would be suitable, some UML. Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: I think I start to see the point of those saying that design patterns are harmful. Just choose the best design for this problem - no matter if it's in [some design pattern bible]. If the design you end up with happens to look like some design someone called the X design pattern, that's okay. It's also okay if it doesn't. But asking "What design pattern fits this problem" is the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a design pattern is a common way to resolve a common problem:

- "how can my code use different algorithms under different circumstances at runtime?" (strategy pattern)
- "how can I implement a complex series of behaviors so that certain subclasses can override certain steps in the series, but inherit others?"  (template method pattern)

There's a great many design-time questions which cannot and shouldn't be answered using a pattern:

- "what pattern should I use to design a User object?" (too granular - doesn't really specify a common problem)
- "what pattern should I use to build an IM client program?" (too abstract - design patterns address common specific problems, not entire software designs)

You've made a good start - you've represented your business data as objects (or in this case, 1 object: XAvatar) and you've defined a service API (XCommands).  As you continue design/development from this point, you'll hit some more specific snags or problems.  Very likely, some of those will be common problems many other developers have encountered before: **THAT'S** when design patterns will help you.